# Verification of a logarithmic inequality

Tags: calculus, analysis, inequality, logarithms

Verify the inequality
$ \frac{(\log (x) + \log (y))}{2} \le \log\frac{(x+y)}{2}$, where $x,y>0$

I'm still struggling how to solve the inequality, I have tried AM-GM and Bernoulli, without any success.My suggestion is that the solution is very elementare, but I can't see it.

Comment: This is just concavity of logarithm. Its second derivative is negative so it is concave.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\log$ is a concave function, which says that your inequality is true by Jensen.

About Jensen see here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jensen%27s_inequality

Answer (score 2):

You have\begin{align}\frac{\log(x)+\log(y)}2&=\frac12\log(xy)\\&=\log\left(\sqrt{xy}\right)\\&\leqslant\log\left({\frac{x+y}2}\right).\end{align}

Comment: $ 0\le ({\sqrt x}-{\sqrt y})^{2}  \iff  0\le x-2{\sqrt {xy}}+y \iff  2{\sqrt {xy}}\le x+y \iff {\sqrt {xy}}\le {x+y\over2}$ Can I use it to show the inequality above? My only problem is to show, that the logarithm want have an influence on these steps.

Comment: That is correct, but it is just the AM-GM inequality.